# XSLT parse Elements for String and preceding siblings

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem with following task.

My XML example is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<doors>
<module>
    <object>
        <object_type>heading</object_type>
        <object_level>1</object_level>
        <Object__Heading>Functions</Object__Heading>
    </object>
    <object>
        <object_type>heading</object_type>
        <object_level>2</object_level>
        <Object__Heading>not_interesting</Object__Heading>
    </object>
    <object>
        <object_type>text</object_type>
        <object_level></object_level>
        <Object__Heading>not_interesting</Object__Heading>
        <Object___Text>SignalName1</Object___Text>
        <RB_Signal_Type>boolean</RB_Signal_Type>
        <RB_Signal_Min></RB_Signal_Min>
    </object>
    <object>
        <object_type>text</object_type>
        <object_level></object_level>
        <Object__Heading>not_interesting</Object__Heading>
        <Object___Text>SignalName2</Object___Text>
        <RB_Signal_Type>u_int8</RB_Signal_Type>
        <RB_Signal_Min></RB_Signal_Min>
    </object>
    <object>
        <object_type>heading</object_type>
        <object_level>1</object_level>
        <Object__Heading>CAN</Object__Heading>
    </object>
    <object>
        <object_type>text</object_type>
        <object_level></object_level>
        <Object__Heading>not_interesting</Object__Heading>
        <Object___Text>SignalName3</Object___Text>
        <RB_Signal_Type>boolean</RB_Signal_Type>
        <RB_Signal_Min></RB_Signal_Min>
    </object>
</module>
</doors>
```

I want to Parse the SignalName in `<Object__Text>`, then get the sibling Informations about the `<Signal_Type>` and <`Signal Min>`. 
I am able to do this with following XSL Part:

```
<TT><xsl:value-of select="concat('Signal_Type: ',document('SSTbytool.xml')/doors/module/object[Object___Text = $SignalName]/RB_Signal_Type)"/></TT>
<TT><xsl:value-of select="concat('Signal_Min: ',document('SSTbytool.xml')/doors/module/object[Object___Text = $SignalName]/RB_Signal_Min)"/></TT>
```

This Part is in the Transformation XSLT file.
The required additional information is in an external xml (let's call it Group.xml), thats why I am using the document() function.
The Problem now is, that I also need to know, under which `<Object__Heading>`
this Signal-Element is. E.g. SignalName1 is under Object__Heading Functions and  SignalName3 under CAN.

I've tried this Code but it didn't work:

```
<xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::document('SSTbytool.xml')/doors/module/object[Object___Text = $SignalName][object_type = 'heading' and object_level = '1' and Object___Heading = 'Functions']">
```

For a better understanding: I have to diffrent xml files, let's assume it's Group.xml and this example.xml . Then I am using a XSLT to transform the Group.xml in an Output.xml. But the example.xml contains additional information which I want to add. So I take the SignalName variable (consists a String from the Group.xml) and want to add the additional Informations for this variable from the example.xml.

So my intended Output should be sth. like:

```
<TT>Signal_Name: SignalName1</TT>
<TT>Signal_Type: boolean</TT>
<TT>Signal_Min:</TT>
<TT>Object__Heading : Functions</TT>

<TT>Signal_Name: SignalName2</TT>
<TT>Signal_Type: u_int8</TT>
<TT>Signal_Min:</TT>
<TT>Object__Heading : Functions</TT>

<TT>Signal_Name: SignalName3</TT>
<TT>Signal_Type: boolean</TT>
<TT>Signal_Min:</TT>
<TT>Object__Heading : CAN</TT>
```

I don't know how to get the right Object_Heading argument.

Somebody can help me here? Or has even an easier way to do this?

I hope you understand my question!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where (in what context) are you when you're doing this? How did you define the $SignalName variable? And what your intended output?

Comment: So I edited my previouse post. I hope it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still very confusing. Let's suppose the following input:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <string>SignalName1</string>
    <string>SignalName2</string>
    <string>SignalName3</string>
</root>
```

and an additional XML document named SSTbytool.xml which contains what you show in your question.

Applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="lookupdoc" select="document('SSTbytool.xml')" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="string"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="string">
    <xsl:variable name="object" select="$lookupdoc/doors/module/object[Object___Text = current()]" />
    <signal>
        <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </name>
        <type>
            <xsl:value-of select="$object/RB_Signal_Type"/>
        </type>
        <min>
            <xsl:value-of select="$object/RB_Signal_Min"/>
        </min>
        <heading>
            <xsl:value-of select="$object/preceding-sibling::object[object_type='heading' and object_level='1'][1]/Object__Heading"/>
        </heading>
    </signal>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce this **result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <signal>
      <name>SignalName1</name>
      <type>boolean</type>
      <min/>
      <heading>Functions</heading>
   </signal>
   <signal>
      <name>SignalName2</name>
      <type>u_int8</type>
      <min/>
      <heading>Functions</heading>
   </signal>
   <signal>
      <name>SignalName3</name>
      <type>boolean</type>
      <min/>
      <heading>CAN</heading>
   </signal>
</root>
```

Comment: Exactly This:     `"$object/preceding-sibling::object[object_type='heading' and object_level='1'][1]/Object__Heading"` what I was looking for. I guess the [1] is for the first match of the siblings, which are fullfilling the conditions in the brackets before?

Comment: "*I guess the [1] is for the first match of the siblings, which are fullfilling the conditions in the brackets before?*" Yes.